# Using Itunes Match as backup

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I have a dilemma, I have over 80GB of music on my computer and I want to free up some space. I am looking at using iTunes Match as storage for my music instead of having it on the laptop but I have a couple of questions about it?

1. Once it is all uploaded to my iCloud and I delete it from my hard drive, will iTunes still work or will it be constantly be looking for the physical files.
2. If I can delete it, how do I upload new music I acquire, do I have to physically put it on iTunes, then upload and then delete?
3. How does it work with my iPhone as I will never have the capacity to load all my songs on the phone.  Is it easy to select an album or genre at a time to download to the phone?

Answer (score 1):

> Once it is all uploaded to my iCloud and I delete it from my hard drive, will iTunes still work or will it be constantly be looking for the physical files.

After uploading all your files to iTunes Match you can delete all your local files. iTunes Match needs not the *original files*.

> If I can delete it, how do I upload new music I acquire, do I have to physically put it on iTunes, then upload and then delete?

You answered your question by yourself. That is the correct workflow.

> How does it work with my iPhone as I will never have the capacity to load all my songs on the phone. Is it easy to select an album or genre at a time to download to the phone?

A selection by genre is not possible. But you can select by album, artist, playlists, ... .